# Why cant we change the color of badge class in bootstrap 4 using css?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

The class for badge in Bootstrap v4.3.1 is

```
.badge {
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 0.25em 0.4em;
   font-size: 75%;
   font-weight: 700;
   line-height: 1;
   text-align: center;
   white-space: nowrap;
   vertical-align: baseline;
   border-radius: 0.25rem;
   transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, 
   border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
```

and to change its color we can add the following class

```
.badge-success {
   color: #fff;
   background-color: #28a745;
}
```

Logic would say, if I wanted to make my own color I could make a new class in my css file like such

```
.badge-mine {
   color: #212529;
   background-color: #808080;
}
```

and it should work when this works...

```
<span class="badge badge-success">test</span>
```

then this should work too, but it does not work, even though they appear the same.

```
<span class="badge badge-mine">test</span>
```

I have checked many answers, but no one seems to answer why we cannot do it like this. Although, I am no expert in CSS I understand that the last command overwrites the previous one i.e. this should overwrite

```
color: #212529;
background-color: #808080;
```

this

```
color: #fff;
background-color: #28a745;
```

but for some reason it is not happening here.

Can some bootstrap 4 expert shed some light on why the badge-mine does not work even though it looks almost exactly like badge-success?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It should work as intended what you did. But if your two badges

```
<span class="badge badge-success">test</span>
<span class="badge badge-mine">test</span>
```

looks the same the problem is somewhere else, your badge can't have the same style of .badge-success if it doesn't have it as class.
Anyway css class priority works principally on how much specific are them.
For example

```
.badge.badge-success {
   background-color: red;
}
```

overrides

```
.badge-success {
   background-color: green
}
```

You can override this behaviour adding !important to css params, like

```
background-color: red!important;
```

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. I found my problem. My css file was using the old copy. I changed the name of the css file to force it to load. Now it works. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Well it does seem to work as intended:

```css
.badge-mine {
   color: #212529;
   background-color: #808080;
}

.badge-mine-2 {
   color: #ff3300;
   background-color: #0022ff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="badge badge-mine">test</span>
<span class="badge badge-mine-2">test</span>
```

Comment: Yes. I tried it in the file itself, and it works, whereas, when I add it to the style sheet it does not work, although the style sheet loads last. Could you give some reason why that would be? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could custom the bootstrap badge color with this...

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
  color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<p class="badge red">test</p>
```